# Order by certain enum values first

Tags: postgresql, order-by, enum

I've got a table like:

```
╔═══╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ID ║ type (enum)        ║ updated_at  ║
╠═══╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ friend_request     ║ <date_time> ║
║ 2 ║ new_article        ║ <date_time> ║
║ 3 ║ article_read       ║ <date_time> ║
║ 4 ║ article_invitation ║ <date_time> ║
╚═══╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I would like to order the retrieved results by the value of the enum type.

Records with value `friend_request` and `article_invitation` for the `type` column should come first, then the rest. Everything together should be ordered by `updated_at DESC`.

Now, I know I can chain multiple `order by` properties, so f.e.

```
order by type desc, updated_at desc
```

will order for me by `type` and the result of that by the `updated_at` values. But how do I specify for *certain values* of the `type` column? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression:

```
order by case "type"
            when 'article_invitation' then 1
            when 'new_article' then 2
            when 'article_read' then 3
            when 'friend_request' then 4
         end, 
         updated_at desc
```

Comment: Can I specify only `friend_request` and `article_invitation` in the `case` expression and leave the rest at random, therefore to be enforced only by the `updated_at desc`?

Comment: @Milkncookiez: sure

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! And for the ones wondering how to do this with [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#ordering-and-grouping) - use `sequelize.literal('case ... when ... end')` in the `order: []` property.